# ray on jruby, opengl

Tags: ruby, opengl, jruby

I'm using Ray (https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/ray) and I can't seem to get it to work with JRuby on Windows. The author said he tested it with JRuby and Rubinius so I gave it a try. It obviously didn't work as there are native extensions required. Is there a way I can get it to work?

```
--> jgem install ray
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ray:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        c:/jruby-1.6.7/bin/jruby.exe extconf.rb
WARNING: JRuby does not support native extensions or the `mkmf' library very well.
Check http://kenai.com/projects/jruby/pages/Home for alternatives.
checking for GL/glxext.h... no
checking for X11/extensions/Xrandr.h... no
checking for main() in -lXrandr... no
checking for main() in -lX11... no
*** extconf.rb failed ***
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The [extconf.rb](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/ray/blob/master/ext/extconf.rb) file is using `RUBY_PLATFORM` to include the right dependencies.
2. It's looking for [`RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mingw/`](https://github.com/Mon-Ouie/ray/blob/master/ext/extconf.rb#L20)
3. Jruby sets it's `RUBY_PLATFORM` as java. Try it out by running `ruby -e 'puts RUBY_PLATFORM'`.
4. You could try changing `extconf.rb` to match against `/mingw|java/`.
5. You could also try using MRI ruby.

Comment: I'm using MRI for my project but I wanted to try JRuby for deployment without the source. I did as you suggested and built the gem with changed extconf.rb but it didn't work.

Comment: If you want to use Jruby, you must make the above mentioned changes to extconf.rb.

Comment: Setting the regexp to that wouldn't work, assuming it does the same on Linux and other platforms.